# How to separate a DataFrame column in two given a delimiter?

Tags: julia

Given a DataFrame `df` in Julia:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(X = ['A', 'B', 'C'], Y = ["a|b", "a|c", "b|b"])
```

How can I create columns Y1 and Y2 by splitting column Y at the "|" delimiter?

E.g., in R tidyverse I'd do:

```
separate(df, Y, c("Y1", "Y2"), by = "\\|")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no in-built function that does this as far as I know.

Two relatively terse ways to do it that come to my mind are either:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(X = ['A', 'B', 'C'], Y = ["a|b", "a|c", "b|b"])
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ X    │ Y      │
│     │ Char │ String │
├─────┼──────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 'A'  │ a|b    │
│ 2   │ 'B'  │ a|c    │
│ 3   │ 'C'  │ b|b    │

julia> data = split.(df.Y, '|')
3-element Array{Array{SubString{String},1},1}:
 ["a", "b"]
 ["a", "c"]
 ["b", "b"]

julia> foreach(enumerate([:Y1, :Y2])) do (i, n)
           df[!, n] = getindex.(data, i)
       end

julia> df
3×4 DataFrame
│ Row │ X    │ Y      │ Y1        │ Y2        │
│     │ Char │ String │ SubStrin… │ SubStrin… │
├─────┼──────┼────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 'A'  │ a|b    │ a         │ b         │
│ 2   │ 'B'  │ a|c    │ a         │ c         │
│ 3   │ 'C'  │ b|b    │ b         │ b         │
```

or

```
julia> df = DataFrame(X = ['A', 'B', 'C'], Y = ["a|b", "a|c", "b|b"])
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ X    │ Y      │
│     │ Char │ String │
├─────┼──────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 'A'  │ a|b    │
│ 2   │ 'B'  │ a|c    │
│ 3   │ 'C'  │ b|b    │

julia> hcat(df, DataFrame(reduce(vcat, permutedims.(split.(df.Y, '|'))), [:Y1, :Y2]))
3×4 DataFrame
│ Row │ X    │ Y      │ Y1        │ Y2        │
│     │ Char │ String │ SubStrin… │ SubStrin… │
├─────┼──────┼────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 'A'  │ a|b    │ a         │ b         │
│ 2   │ 'B'  │ a|c    │ a         │ c         │
│ 3   │ 'C'  │ b|b    │ b         │ b         │
```

#### EDIT

Currently DataFrames.jl allows you to do it in a simpler way (the current DataFrames.jl release is 1.3):

```
julia> df = DataFrame(X = ['A', 'B', 'C'], Y = ["a|b", "a|c", "b|b"])
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ X     Y      
     │ Char  String 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │ A     a|b
   2 │ B     a|c
   3 │ C     b|b

julia> transform!(df, :Y => ByRow(x -> split(x, '|')) => [:Y1, :Y2])
3×4 DataFrame
 Row │ X     Y       Y1         Y2        
     │ Char  String  SubStrin…  SubStrin… 
─────┼────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ A     a|b     a          b
   2 │ B     a|c     a          c
   3 │ C     b|b     b          b
```

and with DataFramesMeta.jl it would be:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(X = ['A', 'B', 'C'], Y = ["a|b", "a|c", "b|b"])
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ X     Y      
     │ Char  String 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │ A     a|b
   2 │ B     a|c
   3 │ C     b|b

julia> @rtransform!(df, $[:Y1, :Y2]=split(:Y, '|'))
3×4 DataFrame
 Row │ X     Y       Y1         Y2        
     │ Char  String  SubStrin…  SubStrin… 
─────┼────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ A     a|b     a          b
   2 │ B     a|c     a          c
   3 │ C     b|b     b          b
```

which I think is quite clean.

Comment: Another valuable lesson here, thanks Bogumił! It feels a little awkward for a common dataframe action, maybe there is something new out there.

Comment: You are right :) - I have updated the post with the recommended way to do it with DataFrames.jl in its current release.

Answer (score 2):

A'm new in Julia, but I tried this solution and worked.

```
df[:,:Y1]=[i[1] for i in [split(i,"|") for i in df[:,2]]]
df[:,:Y2]=[i[2] for i in [split(i,"|") for i in df[:,2]]]
```

It's ok or is too bad?

Comment: If you are asking something better delete this. If you are trying to answer you need to change the style considerably, to make it give the impression of being a confident and helpful statement.

Comment: This works! Interesting use of comprehensions here, this is instructive though not quite readable.

Answer (score 1):

I learned a bit from [this julia discourse post](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/split-column-in-dataframe/68036/2), there is a nicer way. This is idiomatic in the DataFrames world:

```
transform(df, :Y => ByRow(x -> split(x, "|")) => [:Y1, :Y2])

#3×4 DataFrame
# Row │ X     Y       Y1         Y2
#     │ Char  String  SubStrin…  SubStrin…
#─────┼────────────────────────────────────
#   1 │ A     a|b     a          b
#   2 │ B     a|c     a          c
#   3 │ C     b|b     b          b

# its even nicer if the delimiter is whitespace:
transform(df, :Y => ByRow(split) => AsTable)
```

I haven't tested where the number of fields from the split are uneven, I suspect the way to go in that case is `flatten` and then `unstack`.

I'll add a shout to the DataFramesMeta way of formulating syntax which is so nice IMO:

```
using DataFramesMeta

@rtransform df $[:Y1, :Y2] = split(:Y, "|")

# 3×4 DataFrame
# Row │ X     Y       Y1         Y2
#     │ Char  String  SubStrin…  SubStrin…
#─────┼────────────────────────────────────
#   1 │ A     a|b     a          b
#   2 │ B     a|c     a          c
#   3 │ C     b|b     b          b
```